# Pass a Jasmine spec on async timeout

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine2.0

Running Jasmine 2.8.

I've got a test case in which the failure case is an event handler being triggered under a condition when it should not be. Note that the codebase that provides events here is part of a proprietary, developed-in-house system and as such these are not DOM events and I am not leveraging any popular JS frameworks:

```
    it('should trigger the event handler in state 0', function (done) {
        function specCb(ev) {
            expect(ev).toBeDefined();
            expect(ev.data).toBe('some value');
            done();
        }
        thing.state = 0;
        simulateEventTrigger(thing, specCb);
    });

    it('should not trigger the event handler in state 1', function (done) {
        function specCb(ev) {
            done.fail('this should not be called in state 1');
        }
        thing.state = 1;
        simulateEventTrigger(thing, specCb);
    });
```

The second spec will always fail because either the callback is called, which explicitly fails the spec, or the spec times out waiting for `done()` to be called, thus failing it. How do I get Jasmine to *pass* a spec if it times out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [spies](https://jasmine.github.io/2.8/introduction.html#section-Spies) in Jasmine. Spies allow you to "spy on" a function and assert whether it has been called and with which arguments. Or, in your case, whether it has not been called. An example might look like this...

```
describe("A spy", function() {
  var evHandlers;

  beforeEach(function() {
    evHandlers = {
       callback: function (e) {}
    }

    spyOn(evHandlers, 'callback');
  });

  it('should not trigger the event handler in state 1', function (done) {
      thing.state = 1;
      simulateEventTrigger(thing, evHandlers.callback);
      expect(evHandlers.callback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually `it` function accepts the callback so you could do something like this:

```js
const TEST_TIMEOUT = 1000;
const CONSIDER_PASSED_AFTER = 500;

describe('a test that is being considered passing in case of a timeout', () => {
    it('should succeed in after a specified time interval', done => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            done();
        }, CONSIDER_PASSED_AFTER);
    }, TEST_TIMEOUT);
});
```